# Child Theme's style.css not loading in mobile browser

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

Recently, I tried to customize some Wordpress page. I started by creating a child-theme of the twentythirteen template.
Therefore, I've created a new directory, called it twentythirteen-child, added a style.css file containing all the needed information and it worked.
It works on my Desktop chrome browser, it works on my Samsung Internet Browser app on my phone, but somehow it does neither work on my phone's google chrome app, nor on the iphone's safari browser.
How could that possibly be? 
Also, I read that one should add these lines to the functions.php in my child theme:

```
// Queue parent style followed by child/customized style
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles/child-style.css', array( 'parent-style' ) );
}
```

This changes my complete style-less website on my phone to a classic twentythirteen theme instead of the expected twentythirteen-child theme.

Why do mobile phones load no stylesheet or the parent's stylesheet (if the php code is added) instead of the child-theme? I am looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Are your child styles in `/styles/child-style.css` or `style.css` of the child theme?  Did you try to clear the cache on your mobile Chrome and Safari apps?

Comment: @Mike the child stlyes are in /styles/twentythirteen-child/style.css. I will try clearing the cache and see if it helps. Thanks!